# navigate between xib view files

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I'm working on a project, the project doesn't have storyboards, it just have a views as xib files with its own class , the question is : how can I navigate between these xib views ?
or is it possible to embed them in navigation controller ?

I try this code but nothing happened ?

```
let NC = UINavigationController()

 @IBAction func showUserProfile(_ sender: Any) {
    
    print("show Profile")
    let vc = UserProfile(
    nibName: "UserProfile",
    bundle: nil)
    NC.pushViewController(vc,
    animated: true )
}
```

this is in app delegate

```
 let mainView = BlockListViewController(nibName: "BlockListViewController", bundle: nil)
    window?.addSubview(mainView)
    let navigationControll = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainView)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationControll
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and I try to navigate when event occur using this

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UserProfile(), animated: true)
```

Comment: you can't you can add those views in VC and navigate that

Comment: how can navigate between them ? I set one as initial view controller but I need to navigate between these xib views

Comment: check my answer and ill update a workaround regard this comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't navigate between instances of `UIView`

according to apple `UINavigationController`

> A container view controller that defines a stack-based scheme for navigating hierarchical content.
>
> A navigation controller is a container view controller that manages
> one or more child view controllers

so basically a stack of `UIViewController`, defined as `[UIViewController]`

read more about it in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

What you can do is adding each `UIView` in a `UIViewController` and navigate thru that simply.

According to your comment you can predefined them into instance of VC and create a `UINavigationController` with you'r initial then simply push to the desired `UIViewController` from the `UINavigationController`

**COMMENT UPDATE**

As I got from your comment in the main view you already defining the `UINavigationController` simply replace  `NC.pushViewController(vc,animated: true )`
with  `self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true )`

The problem is you are creating new `UINavigationController` while you already have the first one embedded

Comment update:
if you're using iOS 13+ with scene delegate use this inside `willConnectTo`

```
   guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    // Instantiate UIWindow with scene
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    // Assign window to SceneDelegate window property
    self.window = window
    // Set initial view controller from Main storyboard as root view controller of UIWindow
    let mainView = BlockListViewController(nibName: "BlockListViewController", bundle: nil)
    let navigationControll = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainView)

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationControll
    // Present window to screen
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and call `self.navigationController.push`

like this

```
@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: UIButton)  {
        let secondView = secondVC(nibName: "secondVC", bundle: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondView, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: this is the first class inherent from UIVewcontroller :
class BlockListViewController: UIViewController
and this is the secondvIew controller 

how can I embed the first one in navigation controller and from it go to the second

these classes views as xib file not storyboard

Comment: the question is (  navigate thru xibs ) answer is no this is a work around I don't know what's your code and the actual problem

Comment: this is the first class inherent from UIVewcontroller : class BlockListViewController: UIViewController and this is the secondvIew controller how can I embed the first one in navigation controller and from it go to the second these classes views as xib file not storyboard –

Comment: why no show the first class from a navigationController ? hide the navigationBar for it if that's the case

Comment: let mainView = BlockListViewController(nibName: "BlockListViewController", bundle: nil)
        let navigationControll = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainView)

Comment: and from mainView how are you trying to push

Comment: check update if you already have the first view in `nav` simply use `self` @QasemM.Zreaq

Comment: navigationControll.pushViewController(secondView, animated: true)
but it doesn't work

Comment: are you creating the instance correctly try to debug and print self.navigationController and when you show the first view SHOW the navigation controller that holds the view not the first view make sure you're doing that can you share how are you showing the first view in the `UIWindow`

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UserProfile(), animated: true)
Doesn't work it may its views not storyboard its xib files !

Comment: this is the first view in app correct ? so you are calling it from app delegate can you show that code fully in the question ?

Comment: I put this in app delegate but also give an error !

 let mainView = BlockListViewController(nibName: "BlockListViewController", bundle: nil)
        window?.addSubview(mainView)
        let navigationControll = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainView)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationControll
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: iOS 13+ ? do you have scene delegate ?

Comment: Yes i have +13  ios and i have scene delegates

Comment: @QasemM.Zreaq good remove it from app delegate and check my updated answer I just tested this it works fine ! .. please et2kad enu el nav ele bn3mlo show meh el view controller we jawato 3ade Nade self.nav.push

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221121/discussion-between-mohmmad-s-and-qasem-m-zreaq).